# Bootstrap Datepicker showing frame but not calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am relatively new to JavaScript and JQuery. I am trying to implement Twitter's bootstrap datepicker on a series of tabs where there is a datepicker on each tab. Right now (single tab), the empty frame pops up on the first click of the icon. Clicking away and clicking the icon again shows the arrows and the days of the week (Sun, Mon, Tues, ...). It doesn't show the month or the day numbers. I've included the CSS, JS, and less in the base.html. My code is below:

JavaScript

```
//implemented within another method
this.$('li.tab i').datepicker('autoclose', true, 'update', Date.today().toString("mm/dd/yyyy")).on('changeDate', function(ev){ this.$('li.tab i').datepicker("show"); });
```

Base.html

```
<head>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="{{ CSS_URL }}/datepicker.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="{{ CSS_URL }}/datepicker.less">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        require = {
                baseUrl: "{{ JAVASCRIPT_URL }}",
                config:{
                    tpl: {
                       variable:'data'
                    }
                },
                shim: {
                    underscore: {
                        exports: '_'
                    },
                    backbone: {
                        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
                        exports: 'Backbone'
                    },
                    bootstrap: ['jquery'],
                    select2: ['jquery'],
                    'backbone.marionette': ['backbone'],
                    'jquery.tokeninput': ['jquery'],
                    'datepicker': ['jquery']
                }
            };
    </script>
</body>
```

Tabs html

```
<li><a class="btn add" href="#"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a></li>
<% for (m in data.models) {%>
    <li class="tab" >
        <a data-model=<%= data.models[m].cid %> href="#datapoint<%= data.models[m].cid %>" data-toggle="tab"><%= data.models[m].get('date') %>
            <div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
                <i class="icon-calendar pull-right" style="margin-left:10px;cursor:pointer;">
                </i>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
<% } %>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I apologize if it's something simple I missed.

**EDIT:** Also, I'm trying to figure out what the HTML inside the  ... > does. If anyone knows a good resource for it/what it's even called, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Can you repro this issue at http://jsfiddle.net/ and then share the link to the fiddle?

Comment: Here's an original one that works: http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/D9Xav/3/. I adapted it to repro my issue http://jsfiddle.net/PdjpD/1/. The main difference between the two is that there's no data-bind and I got rid of the input. Apparently that's necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a date to be selected when the calendar is shown, by setting the `data-date` attribute:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date="05-06-2013" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Here is a working version of your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PdjpD/3/).